# MySQL statement returning none when it shouldnt using fetchone()

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x

This is the only part of the program where an SQL statement returns none for some reason. Any help as to how to fix it would be appreciated. This is the specific statement that doesn't work: `sql = f"SELECT * FROM tbl_run WHERE Hash = \"{self.h}\""`. All of the other statements work using this format but ive tried everything I can think of. The purpose of this statement is to grab the RID from `tbl_run` where the hash is the same - and the hashes are identical as I can see when I run the print statements.

```
def save_db(self):      
        if self.pop_entry.get() == "":
            a = self.pop_entry.get()
            a = int(a)
        else:
            a = 10
        
        if self.gen_entry.get() == "":
            b = self.gen_entry.get()
            b = int(b)
        else:
            b = 5
        
        if self.mut_entry.get() == "":
            c = self.mut_entry.get()
            c = int(c)
        else:
            c = 0.04
        
        if self.chl_entry.get() == "":
            d = self.chl_entry.get()
            d = int(d)
        else:
            d = 100
        
        #writing to tbl_run
        sql1 = f"SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE Username = \"{self.user_reg.get()}\""
        self.dbhandler.execute(sql1)
        result = self.dbhandler.fetchone()

        now = datetime.now()
        dt = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

        self.x = str(dt) + self.file_name_entry.get()
        self.hashed()

        #x = r'{}'.format(self.h)

        sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_run (RID, UID, Date_Time, Name, Hash) VALUES (NULL, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
        val = (result[0], dt, self.file_name_entry.get(), self.h)
        self.dbhandler.execute(sql, val)
        self.db_connection.commit()    
        print("Committed")  
        
        #writing to tbl_data
        sql = f"SELECT * FROM tbl_run WHERE Hash = \"{self.h}\""
        self.dbhandler.execute(sql)
        result = self.dbhandler.fetchone()
        print(sql)
        print(self.h)
        print(result)
```

Comment: Why are you not using parameterised queries for your SELECT queries? Firstly that is a potential SQL injection vulnerability. Second, are you sure that you got the quoting of `self.h` correct? Try: `self.dbhandler.execute("SELECT * FROM tbl_run WHERE Hash = %s", self.h)`

Comment: It might also help to let us know what is the value of `self.h` and the data type of the `Hash` column in the database.

Comment: And check the return values for `self.dbhandler.execute()` to make sure that the INSERT was successful.

Comment: @mhawke this is the function for self.h and the datatype for hash is a varhcar -  `def hashed(self):       
        x = self.x
        self.h = str(sha512(x.encode("utf-16")).digest())[2:-1]`

Comment: What size is the varchar? Possibly the value is being truncated on insertion, assuming that it succeeds. Also, converting the hash to `str` is increasing the size. You should probably use `hexdigest()` and use VARCHAR(128) so that the full hash is stored.

Comment: @mhawke the varchar column has a maximum length of 1000

Comment: What does `self.dbhandler.execute()` return? Also, can you verify the insertion using the mysql cli?

Comment: @mhawke it doesn't return anything, and i dont know what you mean by verify the insertion.

Comment: What database module are you using? By verification I mean to go directly to MySQL using the mysql comand and execute a select query on the table to see if the insertion worked.

Comment: Oh, im using mysql.connector and the insertion does work. I can check the table on phpmyadmin and it shows up there each time

Comment: @mhawke Ive figured out a solution, I've used `sql = f"SELECT * FROM tbl_run WHERE RID = @@IDENTITY"` to retrieve the RID